# SBT setting fallback search path

Tags: sbt

How are you doing?

I did the following in SBT console:

```
inspect version
```

And I get something like the following:

```
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:version
[info]  {.}/*:version
[info]  */*:version
```

So, actually, what's the difference between the last two??? I read and read the documentation but can't seem to make any difference to me. One is ThisBuild (a.k.a. entire build, a.k.a. {.}) while the other one is Global.

Why does {.} in the project axis has precedence over * in the project axis?
The values {.} and * looks pretty much the same to me..

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The order of the last two in:

```
*:version     -> try current project
{.}/*:version  -> try this build
*/*:version   -> try global
```

says that whatever version you specified in this build, you want that to override anything that was possibly defined in Global.

Example:  Key "version"
For Global scope it was defined in Defaults.scala with value "0.1-SNAPSHOT".
For your projects in this build you might want to overwrite that with:

```
version in ThisBuild := "3.0.1"
```

So, because {.}/*:version has precedence over */*:version, whenever you get "version" in your projects, you fetch "3.0.1" instead of "0.1-SNAPSHOT".